# How can I have a value that will be calculated only in the next view?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-animation, mapkit

I'd like to make the following transition animation:

[Transition animation video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1603777/transition.mov)

How can I have the pin x,y target point of the animation while in the list view, so I can perform the animation with the proper initial and final points?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [`convertCoordinate:toPointToView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertCoordinate:toPointToView:) method to translate the map coordinate to a CGPoint for the view.

There's a similar question here: [Convert MKAnnotation Coordinates to View Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421732/convert-mkannotation-coordinates-to-view-coordinates)

Comment: Ok. But I only get the coordinates in the second view (map view). So how can I have the CGPoint in the first view?