# Get frame of annotation on map view

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

In my app I have custom annotations where the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` is a circular `UIView`. This works perfectly in the simulator with this code:

```
    let rideTimeView = UIView()
    rideTimeView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)
    rideTimeView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
```

The problem arises when I run the app on actual devices. It works fine on (I believe) 6 and 6 Plus, but overlaps at the bottom on 4 and 5.

Is there any way I can get the dimensions of the annotation?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421732/convert-mkannotation-coordinates-to-view-coordinates
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

To get the frame of MKAnnotationView in MKMapView, first you will need a reference to the MKAnnotation.  Then do:

```
if let annotationView = self.mapView.view(for: annotation) {
    let frameOfAnnotationViewInMapView = annotationView.frame
}
```

In addition, if you want the frame of the MKAnnotationView on screen, do:

```
let frameOfViewInSuperview = self.mapView.convert(frameOfAnnotationViewInMapView, to: self.mapView.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview)
```

The number of times you need to call .superview will depend on how deep your MKMapView is nested.  For my case, it was nested very deep.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert frame from superview to window:

```
let frame = convertRect(rideTimeView.frame, toView: UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!)
```

Comment: I've tried doing this - `let frame = pinView.convertRect(pinView.frame, toView: UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!)`. pinView is the annotation that I need the frame for, but it just returns (0,0,0,0).

Comment: Try to use `pinView.superview.convertRect`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I should mention that the above code is within `viewForAnnotation`, so at that point would pinView actually have a frame?

Comment: What does debugger show you when you write **"po pinView"** and **"po pinView.superview"**?

Comment: I get (0,0,0,0) with `pinView`, and the app just crashes with nil when I try `pinView.superview!`.

Comment: Did you try to debug view using button on debug panel? Or try to debug view by showing colored frames of each view element?